# why the taphold event not work on button click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to get long press event .So I try taohold event in jquery mobile .But when I add on button it not call.

I do like that on fiddle

```
<button id="test">Test</button>

$('#test').bind('taphold', function(e) {
     alert("jj") ;  
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
} );


$(function(){
  $( "#test" ).bind( "taphold", tapholdHandler );

  function tapholdHandler( event ){
       alert("jjghfhg") ;
  }
});
```

Comment: This code works just fine if used correctly. Basically what I want to tell you your problem is not in this code. Tell me few things. What jQuery Mobile version are you using? Do you use several HTML pages or just one? And do you know what page events are?

Comment: Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/zGqM8/

Comment: The real question is in my fiddle .http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Krukd/1/

Comment: it start scrolling when I click start button .But I need when user tab on any image it start scrolling

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that you are not using jQuery Mobile correctly. For taphold to work correctly you need to bind your event at a precise moment. document ready or $(function(){ can not be used here. Mainly because they will trigger long before jQuery Mobile can restyle its DOM content.

To find out more read my article **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.

That is why I asked you do you know what jQuery Mobile page events are. To make this work your content must be part of a page div and even binding must be executed after pageinit event.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/uBtcL/

**HTML :**

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <button id="test">Test</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $('#test').bind('taphold', function(e) {
        alert("jj") ;  
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } );
});
```

Comment: can you do one more favour

Comment: can we shift one image left and right on swipeleft and swiperight

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Krukd/1/ can we shift one image on left or right whi;e using swipeleft or right

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/96/ You only need to implement other direction

Comment: But It work same (move in same direction ) on swipeleft and swipe right

Comment: It should move left when user swipeleft .and if user swipe right and it should move right

Comment: That's why I told you to implement movement to the other direction. I only gave you an example how to do it correctly with swipe event.

Comment: ok ...Please do do for same for left swipe actually i don't have much idea of animation ..you give good answer .can you help me in last time

Comment: I will do it but you will need to open new question, mainly because this question don't have anything to do with this jsFiddle. Also accept my answer if this is what you have wanted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36926/discussion-between-user2648752-and-gajotres)